# How to retrieve "facet_queries" data with SolrJ

Tags: solr

I did not find any way to do that.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve facet queries using the [getFacetQuery() method](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_6_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#getFacetQuery--) and you can append facet queries to a solr query using the [addFacetQuery() method](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_6_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#addFacetQuery-java.lang.String-).

The following example test provided with Solr has some good examples of using facet queries with SolrJ:
[SolrExampleTests.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/solr/tags/release-1.3.0/client/java/solrj/test/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrExampleTests.java)