# Query facet count and its matching documents

Tags: solr, count, faceted-search, solrj

We're running Apache Solr v3.1 and [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) is our client.

We're passing multiple [Arbitrary Faceting Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting) (`facet.query`) to get the
number of matching documents (the facet count) evaluated over the search
results in a *single* Solr query.  My use case demands the actual matching
facet results/documents/fields also along with facet count.

My question is, is it possible to get facet query matching results along
with facet count in a single Solr query call?

Comment: If only you tried :-) The documents are returned in `docs` and the facets are returned in `faceting` (alongside the docs). Do extract the HTTP calls SolrJ makes and run them in your browser.

Comment: @aitchnyu: I think you've not understood my question.  I knew documents are returned in `docs`, but my question here is I want to get facet count's results as well in single Solr query call.  Hope I made this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support to get the facet rows count in solr 3.1 to my knowledge. The issue you are looking for exists as a feature request in Solr's JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2242

There is a patch available, even specifically for Solr 3.1, but the issue still remains unresolved / uncommitted in 4.0. Maybe you could apply the patch yourself and see how it works out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that link. I could see that the JIRA issue is being discussed with `facet.field`.  Any idea or guess on whether this same patch is applicable for Arbitrary Query Faceting (`facet.query`) also?

Comment: Ok I misundestood, do you just need to get the facet.query results using SolrJ? Maybe this answers your question then: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299732/how-to-retrieve-facet-queries-data-with-solrj](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299732/how-to-retrieve-facet-queries-data-with-solrj)

Comment: Still your initial understanding of my question is right. Anyhow, let me try to explain this with an example.  For instance, if I've 2 facet queries (`facet.query`) which has 40 and 50 matching documents respectively.  I want the documents (result) itself of each 40 and 50 counts that matched the facet query.  I think the JIRA issue link provided by you have addressed my need for `facet.field`, but in my case, I'm using Arbitrary Query Faceting (`facet.query`).

Comment: OK, so you need the actual results to go along with the counts. I don't think that this is possible with the facet component (it just returns the counts). There is another feature, called Result Grouping / Field Collapsing [http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) that might be useful for your case, although it appears after Solr 3.3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'll try out *Result Grouping / Field Collapsing*.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I'm finding `Result Grouping / Field Collapsing` is the right solution to go with for my use case.  Thanks again!